# How to query a value containing backslashes in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a postgresql database that contains file paths, something like this:

```
create table test (path varchar(1024));
insert into test values('c:\foo\bar');
```

If I try to match a path using psycopg2, it doesn't work:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
cx = pg.connect()
cu = cx.cursor()
cu.execute(
    'select * from test where path like %(path)s', 
    {'path': r'c:\foo\bar'}
)
print(cu.fetchall())
```

This code returns no results.

The problem seems to be that Python is escaping the backslashes internally, then psycopg2's parameter escaping escapes them again, so what gets passed to postgresql looks like this:

```
select * from test where path like 'c:\\\\foo\\\\bar'
```

(I determined this using cursor.mogrify()).

How can one avoid this and actually query strings with backslashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in `like`, because backslash is [the default escape character](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) in a pattern.

Use the equality operator:

```
cu.execute(
    'select * from test where path = %(path)s', 
    {'path': r'c:\foo\bar'}
)
```

or `like` with doubled backslashes in the pattern:

```
cu.execute(
    'select * from test where path like %(path)s', 
    {'path': r'c:\\foo\\bar'}
)
```

or `like` with the `escape` clause (e.g. with `chr(94) = '^'`):

```
cu.execute(
    'select * from test where path like %(path)s escape chr(94)',
    {'path': r'c:\foo\bar'}
)
```

Comment: Thanks; this information is now added to the official documentation after I reported it to the maintainer.